# trap access vba messages

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm developing in Access 2007 after a period doing other things and am trying to trap messages to the user. One function in a form modifies a row in a table. The relevant bits of the code are

```
On Error GoTo PROC_ERR
...
DoCmd.RunSQL szSQL
...
PROC_ERR:
  MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical
```

The SQL statement is correct and he system pops up with a "You are about to update 1 row ..." message (number 10505). I want to trap this and replace it with my own warning message. However, my function doesn't trap an error on this message. Nor does it do so on the message that appears if the user clicks "no": "Run-time error 2501. The RunSQL action was canceled."

In VBA options I have for the moment set Error Trapping to "Break on all errors".

What am I missing here? Have I failed to set some other option in Access?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to do not use `RunSQL`. It requires `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`, which may affect further warnings in case if it won't be followed by `DoCmd.SetWarnings True`, for instance after error. Also you won't be able to read quantity of affected rows.
Use

```
db.Execute szSQL, dbFailOnError
```

instead, it will allow to trap errors and analyze database state after query execution. Without `dbFailOnError` option errors won't be raised.

Comment: Yes, I'm glad to have learned about db.Execute. But my function is still not trapping errors such as the 3200 one "record cannot be deleted or changed". Any help with this would stop me tearing my hair in frustration. If you need the complete code of the function rather than the snippet I posted earlier I can supply it.

Comment: Something wrong with your code. Please provide it. About replacing messages like 10505 - just use your own message box before executing the SQL

Answer (score 0):

That message is not an error.

You can silent it with

```
 DoCmd.SetWarnings False
```

Remember to set them on again.

Comment: Fair enough. But I assumed that as the message appeared in the standard list of MS Access error messages that it was trappable as though it were an error. What about the other error (2501)? Shouldn't that be trapped?

Comment: Yes, easily - but you could also replace `DoCmd.RunSQL` with `CurrentDb.Execute` to get passed this in a snap.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the alternative function. It works nicely without the intrusive messages. But I've just tried it with a delete query, which fails because of a relationship issue; it throws a 3200 error "record cannot be deleted or changed". Like the 2501 error this isn't trapped by my error handler. Sorry to keep pressing you on this but I seem to be seriously misunderstanding error handling!

Comment: Well, then you will have to adjust your error handler to handle this and other selected errors politely. Lots of examples around for the browsing.